# Implementation does not take action on behalf of the caller

Tags: java

I'm trying to do the challenge in [this link](http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/topic-11367qaage/Design-Patterns-Java-26.html), however I'm failing to understand what we're supposed to do. The exercise reads:

> Give an example of an interface with methods that do not imply
>   responsibility on  the part of the implementing class to take action
>   on behalf of the caller or to return a value.

I'm confused by the part where they say that the implementing class does not imply responsability on behalf of the caller. What does this mean? My understanding is that the implementing class shouldn't call the Main method. But wouldn't that be strange? I mean, the implementing class it's never supposed to call the Main method. The Main method should call the implementing class (or interface), not the other way around. Is this correct?

I'm not looking for you to give me a solution with code, only in understanding the problem.

Comment: I think the explanation is at the end of the previous page: http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/topic-11367qaage/Design-Patterns-Java-25.html.

Comment: @JBNizet the part where it says "Sometimes, the methods that an interface designates do not carry an obligation to perform a  service for the caller. In some cases, the implementing class can even ignore the call,  implementing a method with no body whatsoever."? I saw that, but it seems they are talking about different things. If it's just a matter of a implementation not overriding all the abstract methods, I'm familiar with the concept, but phrased like this confuses me. Is this just about abstract class methods override? Sorry, I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: @sedulam - Did you check the example WindowsAdapter class they have cited. It is an abstract class which implements all methods of Interface WindowsListener. And all the methods that they have implemented are empty. Check the src code yourself here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public abstract class WindowAdapter extends Object
    implements WindowListener, WindowStateListener, WindowFocusListener
```

> An abstract adapter class for receiving window events. The methods in this class are empty. This class exists as convenience for creating listener objects.
>   Extend this class to create a WindowEvent listener and override the methods for the events of interest. (If you implement the WindowListener interface, you have to define all of the methods in it. This abstract class defines null methods for them all, so you can only have to define methods for events you care about.)
>
> Create a listener object using the extended class and then register it with a Window using the window's addWindowListener method. When the window's status changes by virtue of being opened, closed, activated or deactivated, iconified or deiconified, the relevant method in the listener object is invoked, and the WindowEvent is passed to it.

Comment: I think the key that you are confused about is this concept which is introduced here with - If you implement the WindowListener interface, you have to define all of the methods in it. This abstract class defines null methods for them all, so you can only have to define methods for events you care about.